# Is it possible to select multiple elements in the Chrome Developer Tools Elements panel?

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, developer-tools

Is it possible to select more than one element at a time in the Chrome Developer Tools Elements panel? Would be useful for deleting multiple sibling elements or quick re-ordering. I expected `Command + Click` or `Shift + Click` to do this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is NO, it is not possible to select more than one element at a time in the Chrome Dev-Tools. You may refer to the Chrome Dev-Tools Tips and Tricks
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the link though, some of these tips look pretty useful!

Answer (score 6):

Go to the parent that contains all of the html elements that you want to influence ... 
edit as html. Then you can modify everything inside however you want!

Answer (score 2):

you can copy the entire html by right clicking on the highest html tag above and then select copy outer html(or copy as html in older versions)-> paste it in your code editor->save the document as .html ->click your formatter key combination to format the document(otherwise it would look terrible)->voila you can take whatever you need now.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is NO: While you cannot select an arbitrary set of elements, you can modify settings of groups of elements indicated by tag or class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use shift+click to select multiple elements by the use of a propreitary web extension/addon: [webscraper.io](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper-free-web-scra/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn)

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CtbZub5ny0) demonstrating this is available on their youtube channel

Some useful hints on how the creator does this is available on [github](https://github.com/martinsbalodis/css-selector)

Although, it would be nice if browsers supported this natively!

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the entire element by pressing Ctrl + U on windows.