# With Chrome Dev Tools, how do I view / inspect all the elements at once to see the page layout? (Example attached)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

With Chrome Dev Tools, how do I view / inspect all the elements at once to see the page layout? (Example attached)

Thanks!!!

['View All' Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp20k.jpg)

More Info:
I took the screenshot myself yesterday, but after selecting something else, could never figure out how to replicate this view.

I have found this similar question:
[Is it possible to select multiple elements in the Chrome Developer Tools Elements panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489636/is-it-possible-to-select-multiple-elements-in-the-chrome-developer-tools-element)

The answer given is 'NO', but considering I took this screenshot myself yesterday... I know there is a way.... Thanks!!!

Comment: Where did the screenshot come from?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but here is one trick I use to see all the elements' boxes: In chrome dev tools, click on the `+` symbol at the top right to create a new css rule. Change the selector to `*` to select all elements. Add this css declaration: `outline: 1px solid purple`. This will add a purple outline to all elements on the page.

Comment: I took this screenshot yesterday myself.... But not sure what I had selected to create it... Did your 'outline: 1px solid purple'... it gives a nice view... Although I wish I had an easy way to get a view like the one attached... It seems like this would be very useful to quickly see what is going on, for any page...

Comment: I don't know how to do that. If you fine out how to do it, you should add an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489636/is-it-possible-to-select-multiple-elements-in-the-chrome-developer-tools-element

Comment: I know.. I found that previous question... but considering I had taken this screenshot myself earlier in the day, I know it can be done. somehow.... will continue to investigate....

Comment: define a rule for a universal selector `*` and hover over that in the styles panel of DevTools.

Answer (score 4):

Ankith answered this correctly:

> define a rule for a universal selector * and hover over that in the
>   styles panel of DevTools.

[Screenshot of Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOoE1.jpg)

To replicate this, Kodos had most of it:

> In chrome dev tools, click on the + symbol at the top right to create
>   a new css rule. Change the selector to * to select all elements

(and hover over this selector with the mouse)

Thanks!!!